# Redis server service keeps activating forever

Tags: redis, systemd

Anytime I use `sudo systemctl start redis-server` the activating shell/process does not finish.

The `systemctl status redis-server` shows

```
activating (start) since Thu 2021-01-07 22:13:35 CET; 1min 52s ago
```

The server runs

$ redis-cli ping
-> PONG

But I am wondering how this service can be enabled properly.
My *redis-server.service*

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/redis-server.service
# example systemd service unit file for redis-server
#
# In order to use this as a template for providing a redis service in your
# environment, _at the very least_ make sure to adapt the redis configuration
# file you intend to use as needed (make sure to set "supervised systemd"), and
# to set sane TimeoutStartSec and TimeoutStopSec property values in the unit's
# "[Service]" section to fit your needs.
#
# Some properties, such as User= and Group=, are highly desirable for virtually
# all deployments of redis, but cannot be provided in a manner that fits all
# expectable environments. Some of these properties have been commented out in
# this example service unit file, but you are highly encouraged to set them to
# fit your needs.
#
# Please refer to systemd.unit(5), systemd.service(5), and systemd.exec(5) for
# more information.

[Unit]
Description=Redis data structure server
Documentation=https://redis.io/documentation
#Before=your_application.service another_example_application.service
#AssertPathExists=/var/lib/redis
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
## Alternatively, have redis-server load a configuration file:
#ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /path/to/your/redis.conf
LimitNOFILE=10032
NoNewPrivileges=yes
#OOMScoreAdjust=-900
#PrivateTmp=yes
Type=notify
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
TimeoutStopSec=infinity
UMask=0077
#User=redis
#Group=redis
#WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Few lines from */etc/redis/redis.conf*

```
bind 127.0.0.1
timeout 0
daemonize no
supervised systemd
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
```

I can see just exactly one warning in the log file:

```
61912:M 07 Jan 2021 22:33:08.494 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
```

Any idea?

Comment: set `vm.overcommit_memory=1 ` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or run `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1`

Comment: @Evhz this did not help.

Comment: any update on how this is fixed...?

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but it may help others...

I had this problem in a slightly different context -- a systemd service to run Redis in a container with Podman -- but I suspect the solution is similar. The problem is that

```
Type=notify
```

requires that the service is able to notify systemd when the process has finished starting. If that doesn't happen then systemd will be stuck in 'activating (start)' for obvious reasons, **even if the service starts successfully**.

From the systemd docs:

> Behavior of notify is similar to exec; however, it is expected that the
> service sends a "READY=1" notification message via sd_notify(3) or an
> equivalent call when it has finished starting up.

In the OP's case this may be a permissions problem, keeping notify and opening 'NotifyAccess' may allow systemd to see when the redis process has started.

```
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
```

In my case I also had to pass '--sdnotify=conmon' to podman run in the ExecStart command (see [podman run documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#sdnotify-container-conmon-ignore)).

If the a service doesn't support notify it will be necessary to change the type, for example 'Type=simple' or 'Type=forking' -- read the [systemd.service docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) on Type for a full understanding of the ramifications.